# Whenever I try and render the character, the character just comes out grey

Tags: rendering

I make ROBLOX GFX creations. I recently just started using rigs. When I try to render the character, the body just turns grey! I am not sure why this is happening.[image]

[image: They just turn grey.]

Thanks.

Comment: I fixed it, never mind.

Comment: For others can also learn, can you please give the reason.